# Como quitar linea negra

Tags: materialize, navbar

Al aplicar la clase transparent en el nav en materialize aparece una linea negra entre nav y slider como pudiera quitarla por favor si alguien sabe gracias.  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/258149/pexels-photo-258149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="transparent">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo left"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/logo.png"></a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger right"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="acerca.php">Acerca</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<ul id="mobile-demo" class="sidenav">
  <li>
    <div class="user-view">
      <div class="background"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-320-240-5.jpg"></div>
      <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">Ing. Julio César Castillo Hernández</span></a>
      <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">contacto@softwareeconomico.com</span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Inicio</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="acerca.php"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Acerca</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">restaurant</i>Productos</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">email</i>Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa no es una línea, es una sombra, se crea con `box-shadow`.

Si bien no es la mejor solución, si no te es posible modificar la hoja de estilos de materialize puedes recurrir a sobreescribir la propiedad poniendole de valor `none` para que no se aplique la sombra.

```css
nav,
.sidenav {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

body {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/258149/pexels-photo-258149.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="transparent">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo left"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/logo.png"></a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger right"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="acerca.php">Acerca</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<ul id="mobile-demo" class="sidenav">
  <li>
    <div class="user-view">
      <div class="background"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-320-240-5.jpg"></div>
      <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">Ing. Julio César Castillo Hernández</span></a>
      <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">contacto@softwareeconomico.com</span></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Inicio</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="acerca.php"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Acerca</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">restaurant</i>Productos</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="divider"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">email</i>Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta ya no aparece la sombra box-shadow.

Comment: @JulioCesarCastilloHernandez si te sirvió la respuesta se sugiere dar click en el triángulo hacia arriba, si solucionó tu problema en el botón de palomita que aparecen en el lado izquierdo de la pregunta, esto ayuda bastante a la comunidad a solucinar problemas similares más rápidamente

Comment: Gracias soy nuevo ya seleccione la palomita se puso en color verde saludos.